# CSS - there's some sort of margin but there is no property to change

Tags: css

This div takes up the entire horizontal space and leaves no room for subsequent divs so they are forced to the next available horizontal space.

[image]

```
<div id="featured_positions_container">
    [insert_php]
        remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop');
        $args = array('category_name'=>'featured-positions','posts_per_page' => -1);
        $query = new WP_Query($args);
        while($query->have_posts()):
            $query->the_post();
            $div_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()),'full');
            echo '<div class="featured_positions_plates" style="background-image:url('.$div_image[0].')">';
            echo get_the_title();
            echo '</div>';
        endwhile;
    [/insert_php]
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#featured_positions_container{
    width: 90%;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.featured_positions_plates{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0px 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to float something left or maybe display something inline-block?

Comment: I want the plates to site next to each other horizontally. Modifying the display property doesn't seem to have an impact on the orange space which appears in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no margin, that's the element because the display property is block. Change it to inline-block.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ng5k7gug/1/)**

```
<div id="featured_positions_container">
    <div class="featured_positions_plates">1</div>
    <div class="featured_positions_plates">2</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.featured_positions_plates{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0px 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block; // change this to inline-block
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

If you scroll down in the CSS inspector you'll see that margin is NULL

[image]